# How do you rotate a simple rectangular cube at 45 degrees to X and Y co-ordinates

Tags: edit-mode

I have a model which includes a rectangular cube which is positioned at 50 degrees (approx) to the X axis and 40 degrees (approx) to the Y axis.  I place the 3D cursor in the 'middle' at one end and apply rotation to either the X OR Y axis which causes the cube to rotate both on the X and Y axis. How can I rotate on just one axis.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear. Do you want the cuboid to rotate about its _own_ X or Y? Maybe the normal of one of its faces. if the mesh is not aligned to its object-axes?

Comment: i think a sketch or image would help here a lot to make things clear

Comment: Sorry probably difficult to explain properly. I have just added a screen shot of the simple rectangular mesh (which is NOT aligned to either the X or Y axis).  I just want to rotate the mesh so that the end on left of image is higher than the end on the right. When I try selecting say the X axis to rotate the mesh rotate BOTH on the X and Y axis (which I can understand) but that is not what I want. I guess I could rotate the mesh on the Z axis so that it aligns with the X axis, rotate it and then rotate on the Z axis to return it to its original direction but I surely there is an easier way.

Comment: I have uploaded a simple example to demonstrate what I mea. Here is a long mesh rectangular shape which is about 35 degrees to the X axis and when it is rotated it has rotated BOTH on the X and Y axis rather than just on the X axis.

Comment: Hello... sorry, but I'm still unable to catch what you want to say? Do you mean rotation does not work as expected, or is it how to give some other rotation from the point the mesh is in your blend file?

Comment: It is hard to understand just what you want. If what you have is oriented like in your attached .blend file, you should find that applying the current rotation with Ctrl->A, it will then rotate on the X axis only.

Comment: Yes rotation does not work as expected.  Think of it as a children's see saw it rotates in one axis only - each end goes up and down but it does not twist. I can only make rotation work on 1 axis. When  the rectangular mesh which has already been rotated on the Z axis, the sides of the rectangle are neither along the X or Y axis yet I want that rectangle to rotate on one axis only not twist as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching 'Axis' on in your object's Object tab > Viewport Display panel, you can see that the mesh is still aligned to its object axes:

[image]

(You can also see that it's a cube that has been scaled in Object Mode, which, during modelling, is almost never a good idea.. an awful lot of the questions on BSE are about the consequences of non-uniform Object-level scaling. Probably best to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> apply the scale of your object.)

Because the mesh is aligned to its object-axes, (but not the World), the see-saw rotation is about its **Local** X. You can set the Transform Orientation to 'Local', and <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. Local is also the default secondary orientation to Global. Since your Orientation is set to Global, you can also tap X twice: <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robin. Its great someone understood my dilemma. Thanks also for the tip on when to apply scale. I had recently changed from applying all to just applying scale but will now leave that also. I tried your method out and it works exactly as I wanted.

Comment: I just tried something else which also seems to work. I LOCKED the Y rotation box in the transform panel and then rotated the object on the X axis and so the rotation only affected the X axis. Why didn't I think of that before. I have never even noticed the 'lock' icon before Is that a viable solution? Are either your solution work correctly when the 3D cursor is placed at the very end of the object (not in the center)?

Comment: There are 3 things to take into account in an Euler rotation. 1: the direction of the axis-line. 2: A pivot-point the axis-line passes through, to locate it. 3: (unfortunately) the _order of the component rotations. Each local rotation rotates the _axes_ of subsequent rotations. The N-panel rotations are local (remembering they are cumulative). I don't think the lock makes any difference to that.

Comment: Noted thanks.  When I locked the Y rotation box and 'applied' rotation on the X axis the 'plank' rotated the way I wanted. Maybe just good luck maybe.  The reason I applied All Transforms was because I considered my model complete but when I added it (floating dock scenery) to my MS Flight Simulator airport it displayed it with one end (floating) higher than the other and so I decided to apply rotation in Blender to correct that. Alls good now. Thanks